# How to merge pandas dataframes (on a common key) that are dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, merge

I have a dictionary `data` where the values are pandas dataframes:

```
{'x':    player         x1
 0         foo          x_val
 1         bar          x_val

 'y':    player         y1
 0        foo          y_val
 1        bar          y_val
 'z':     player       z1
 0         foo        z_val
 1         bar        z_val
}
```

I would like to merge all of these dataframes on `player` and get the following result:

```
   player    x1      y1      z1
0   foo     x_val  y_val   z_val
1   bar     x_val  y_val   z_val
```

Yes, I know I could just index them and merge like so:

```
df = (data['x']
  .merge(data['y'],on='player',how='outer')
  .merge(data['z'],on='player',how='outer')
)
```

But the problem with this is that the number of items in `data` is variable. Sometimes I might have all of `x`, `y`, and `z`, sometimes I might not have `z`, and sometimes I might also have `a`, etc. etc.. so I can't brute force it like this.

I tried using a try except block, but that didn't work. I thought maybe I could use a for loop and `enumerate()` to try and initiate these merges, but that didn't work either.

Comment: `functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a.merge(b, on='player'), dic.values())` or `pd.concat([d.set_index('player') for d in dic.values()], axis=1).reset_index()`

Comment: The first second one works, but the first one doesn't. Thanks! Not sure why this question was closed. It is more unique than just simple merging...

Comment: Merging multiple dataframes from an iterable has been covered in many QAs already, whether it's a dictionary/list/… doesn't make a significant difference. If you want a fix for the first approach, please provide minimal **reproducible** inputs as code.